# Closed formula for sum of increasing exponents

Tags: closed-form

I have a sum of the form c¹+c²+...cⁿ. Is it possible to obtain a closed formula for this, and if so how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Revised answer after question edit:
What you've written is the sum of a [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). A closed form of the sum is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n C^k=\frac{C(C^n - 1)}{C-1}$$

Comment: So sorry, I wrote the wrong sum, just edited. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks! :) Been way too long since I did math...

Answer (score 2):

Micapps answered the original question $1^n + 2^n + ...$ but then it was edited to $c^1 + c^2 + ...$

The answer to the edited question seems to be:

$$\sum_{p=1}^n c^p=\frac{1 - c^{(n+1)}}{1 - c} - 1$$

Which is based on this formula I got from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFormulas.html:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n=\frac{1 -r^N}{1 - r}$$

Changes:

- The original starts on n=0 instead of 1, so I can subtract that (assuming c^0 is always 1... not imaginary maybe)... now it's a different formula with a different result.
- and I prefer the "n+1" on the right to the "N-1" on the left side, which is just cosmetic.