# Does this sum have a closed formula?

Tags: summation, exponential-sum

$$c^1 + c^2 + \cdots + c^n = c\frac{c^n - 1}{c-1}$$

[Right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586912/closed-formula-for-sum-of-increasing-exponents)?

What about $c^\frac{1}{m} + c^\frac{2}{m}+ ... c^\frac{n}{m}$? Does it also have a closed formula?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d = c^{\frac{1}{m}}$. Then your sum is
$$
d + d^2 + \ldots + d^m,
$$
which you already know how to sum up. Then substitute back in for $d$.

Comment: Sorry, I knew it was something obvious like this. I am lousy at math. Thanks!